# Download multiple files from an FTP using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I'm not at all an expert at VB Scripting, but since it's a requirement at one of my projects for the moment, I am trying to write a VBScript that will GET all files from a specified FTP Folder.

I manage to get a single specified file, but I can't seem to get all files in a folder. Here's the script I'm trying to use:

```
    Dim objOutStream
  Const OpenAsDefault = -2
  Const FailIfNotExist = 0
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\temp\empty.txt", ForWriting, True, TristateFalse)
With objOutStream
    .WriteLine "USER myuser"   ' USERNAME
    .WriteLine "mypass"     ' Password
    .WriteLine "binary"
    .WriteLine "prompt n"
    .WriteLine "lcd /foldertocopyfrom" ' FOLDER I'm changing into
    .WriteLine "mget *"    ' Get all files with today's date in it
    .WriteLine "bye"
    .Close
End With

Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oFTPScriptShell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -s:" & "C:\temp\temp\empty.txt" & " " & "ftp.location.com", 0, True
```

It doesn't give me an error or anything, it basically does nothing (and yes, I'm sure there are files in the /foldertocopy from :-))

Any ideas? Something obvious I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your .Run does not specify the full file spec of your ftp command file.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to add it here, this is however not causing the issue...

Comment: lcd - change *local* working directory; cd - change *remote* working directory. Did you try the commands interactively?

Comment: yes, the weird thing is that when I try my commands in Windows Powershell, and I do cd Import it says "Command Succesfull", but when I do a "dir" command, it doesn't do anything.... just stays there, being occupied...

Comment: Correction, it gives me first:
200 PORT command succesfull
150 Opening ASCII Mode data connection for /bin/ls, then it does nothing :(

Comment: Sounds like a firewall problem; there probably is a firewall or NAT router between your client and the FTP server. You need a ftp client that supports "passive mode"; unfortunately, the Windows command-line FTP client does not support passive mode. Maybe you can use the free Chilkat FTP component to download files (http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatftp.asp); sample scripts: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/ftp.asp .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your solution but had to make a couple small fixes to make it work:

- Added Option Explicit (for better detection of undefined variables)
- Removed the TristateFalse parameter
- Removed `prompt` since toggle since interactive mode is already off
- Changed `bye` to `quit`
- Added -i parameter to the FTP command
- Plus I tested your FTP command on the command line before using it in your script

Here's the modified script

```
Option Explicit

Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objOutStream, objFSO, objShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\temp\empty.txt", ForWriting, True)
With objOutStream
    .WriteLine "USER myuser"   ' USERNAME
    .WriteLine "mypass"     ' Password
    .WriteLine "binary"
    .WriteLine "lcd /foldertocopyfrom" ' FOLDER I'm changing into
    .WriteLine "mget *"    ' Get all files with today's date in it
    .WriteLine "quit"
    .Close
End With

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -i -s:" & "C:\temp\temp\empty.txt" & " " & "ftp.location.com", 0, True
```

Comment: I actually tried it in the command line as well, and realized afterwards that the operation failed due to a corrupt file on the server..

Being fed up with it I developed a console application that does the same thing but has logging etc in it.

Your post has actually helped me a lot though, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do this for you. You can read and examine it's code here:

http://www.naterice.com/articles/51

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code to download from ftp location.

```
Function FTPDownload(sSite, sUsername, sPassword, sRemotePath)
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objOutStream, objjFSO, objShell
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\temp\empty.txt", ForWriting, True)
With objOutStream
    .WriteLine sUsername   ' USERNAME
    .WriteLine sPassword     ' Password
    .WriteLine "binary"
    .WriteLine "cd /"& sRemotePath' FOLDER I'm changing into
    .WriteLine "mget *"    ' Get all files with today's date in it
    .WriteLine "quit"
    .Close
End With
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%Comspec% /c FTP -i -s:" & "C:\temp\temp\empty.txt" & " " & sSite
End Function
```

Note e.g.

sSite : 192.168.0.1