# FTP Upload and download VBscript with shell

Tags: vbscript, ftp

I am required to download a particular file from ftp to my desktop through shell, i found the forum but could not find exactly what i was looking for.

I have actually developed code from my own side,

I made it simple as possible.
 Here it is

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

oShell.sendkeys("%comspec% /c ftp -p:s:c:username@hostip:destination_folder_directive>local_destination")
oshell.sendkeys("password")
```

As I am using a shell command here, first I am entering the username and host

Next I am entering the password, the problem is that the code gets executed successfully, but I am not able to get the intended file. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download multiple files from an FTP using VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280087/download-multiple-files-from-an-ftp-using-vbscript)

Comment: I checked it too but i could not find clarity in it,